# Black Screen using PyGame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently following a tutorial to use `PyGame` building a maze. I'm currently working with **PyCharm**. I've done indentation reformatting, tried to check every single line for possible indentation problems. Looked for `pygame.update`, `pygame.display.flip` . At least I got the windows up and running but its completely black. I tried to comment certain lines but still got the issue. I'm also working with the latest version of python. So here is the code based on the tutorial:

1) `maze.py` (Generates the maze when called)
https://pastebin.com/9KufTJvM

```
 def setup_maze_window(self):
    # Set up window and layers
    pygame.display.set_caption('MyMaze')
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
    self.background = self.background.convert()
    self.background.fill(WHITE)
    self.m_layer = self.m_layer.convert_alpha()
    self.m_layer.fill(NO_COLOR)
    self.s_layer = self.s_layer.convert_alpha()
    self.s_layer.fill(NO_COLOR)
```

2) `generate_maze.py` (Main, calls maze.py)
https://pastebin.com/r2TCsb1T

The complete code is in the links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting to update the display during the main loop.

Add a line to `generate_maze.py`, underneath line 14:

```
def main():
    current_maze = maze.Maze('create')
    create_dfs(current_maze)
    while 1:
        maze.check_for_exit()
        current_maze.refresh_maze_view() # <== add this line
    return
```